# Adding and aligning frequency labels to 100% stacked bar charts in R

Tags: r, label, alignment, bar-chart

I'm trying to add labels with frequency information (not percentages) to 100% stacked bar charts in R.

I'm having issues centering the labels over the correct segments of the bar charts. I'm using the code below. I thought `position=position_fill(vjust=-0.5)` would center the labels appropriately, but apparently that alone is not enough.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- matrix(c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','p','q','r','s','p','q','r','s',81,32,21,75,42,21,95,72),ncol=3)
colnames(df)=c("ID","Class","Frequency")
df<-as.data.frame(df)

fig <-ggplot(df,aes(fill=Class,y=Frequency,x=ID)) + geom_bar(position=position_fill(reverse=TRUE),stat="identity")
fig <- fig + coord_flip()
fig <- fig + geom_text(aes(label=Frequency),position=position_fill(vjust=-0.5))
```

Any and all assistance would be most appropriated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Frequency = as.numeric(Frequency)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ID, y= Frequency, fill=Class)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Frequency),
            position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = .5), size=6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your response. But in your example, the chart isn't a 100% stacked bar chart anymore. That's one of the issues I'm having. I can't seem to achieve both a 100% stacked bar chart while also getting the labels to be placed on the right segment. So I'm trying to have the Frequency axis be percentage, with A and B's bars filling the entire axis up to 100%. Any thoughts on how to achieve that with count labels?

Comment: Try `position_fill()` instead of `position_stack`